# Can I use an object method to filter an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and Javascript OOP in general.  I am hoping to build a reusable angular component where all the control can be tied to an instance of a javascript object.  One weird behavior I've encountered is that trying to filter a collection with a method of a javascript object.

I have an object with a method filterVisible with signature:

```
this.filterVisible = function(item)
```

When I try to use a ng-repeat filtered by that object method method:

```
ng-repeat="item in item1.items | filter: item1.filterVisible"
```

It doesn't seem to work, but if I wrap that object method in a method in my $scope, like this:

```
$scope.filterVisible1 = function(item) {
  return ($scope.item1.filterVisible(item));
}
```

and change my repeat to:

```
ng-repeat="item in item1.items | filter: filterVisible1"
```

It works.

It's a little confusing so I've put it into a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VuolUr?p=info).  Can someone explain why the filter with the scope method works, but the filter with the object method doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in the document, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

```
{{ filter_expression | filter:expression:comparator }}
```

You can use expression with `filter`, and the expression is for evaluation of all properties are **against the scope** doing the evaluation, unlike in JavaScript where the expressions are evaluated against the global window as deccirbe in the documentation, http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression.

Thus, the question to raise is

`item1.filterVisible` is defined in scope? vs. `filterVisible1` is defined in scope?

String "item1.filterVisible" evaluable by Javascript, However it is not proper expression for $scope.$eval() method.

To make it sure your expression is working, run the following in chrome console after click your element.

```
angular.element($0).scope().$eval(<your expression>)
```

Also, I believe object should have meaningful method name. In your case `filterVisible` is somewhat confusing.

-- Edit --
It turns our that the code provided both defined in $scope. I found there is JS error, that error can be fixed by this.

```
  var _this = this;
  this.filterVisible = function(item) {
    return (Math.abs(_this.items.indexOf(item) - _this.selected_id) <= _this.limit);
  }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer. item1 is defined in $scope, and it has a function filterVisible defined.  You can see it in my plunker here: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/VuolUr/

Comment: My apology, I made a wild guess of your code. you have JS error. answer is edited.

Comment: ahh, good catch - i'm new at js and the _this thing still confounds me.  thanks for the help, it works great now!